# Getting and displaying related objects in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I know this is simple, but I can't get my head around how to join some models together to display in my template in Django. I have "groups" that can have several "contacts".

So far I've got:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField()

class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

In my view, at first I assumed that simply getting my groups would also get any attached contacts, however that doesn't appear to be happening as expected:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    groups = Group.objects.all()
    return groups
```

I was expecting to do something like this in my template:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <h2>{{ group.group_name }}</h2>
    {% for c in group.contact %}
        <h3>{{ c.contact_name }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

This isn't working - what am I doing wrong?  What is the correct query in my view to make sure the contact(s) for each group is getting retrieved?

Comment: `{% for c in group.contact_set.all %}`

Comment: As stated in this part of the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/relations/

Comment: Thanks Burhan, the way I was reading the docs, I thought the .contact_set method was to be used in the view, I didn't even think to use it in the template like that. Appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it looks like you've got some of your code from a different place so just so you can fully understand, you can do this in **2 different** ways:

**1)** To access a related object of any kind, being a simple `ForeignKey` or `ManyToMany` you just need to go from the opposite model and use _set like this example:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField()

class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.ForeignKey(Group)

{{ group.contact_set.all }}
```

**2)** You can set up a name different than the default `_set` changing `Contact` like this:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    contact_name = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='contacts')
```

So, `related_name` kwarg set a new name for you instead of the `_set` one:

```
{{ group.contacts.all }}
```

I hope I manage to make it clearer about simple access on models related objects.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had read about the "_set" method, but didn't realise it was to be used in the template. I thought I must have to use it in the view before I started looking at the template...! Thanks for your great answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use it anywhere to access the related object. No problem, I'm glad I could help. :)

Comment: Hi, i know is been a long time since you have answered this question. I am still new to django and i am facing the same problem i tried solution 1 in my models.py but i keep getting `'ForeignKey' object has no attribute contact_set`

Comment: It looks like you're already calling your foreign key object. Can you share your code here? Otherwise, try changing contact_set to `all()`