# related models queries in django

Tags: django, database, django-templates, django-queryset

I have tree models related to each others as follow :

The first class has basic informations about the project.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    customer =  models.ForeignKey(
                                settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete = models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

The second class is used to register the categories related to every project.

```
class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
                                Project,
                                on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    projectCategory = models.ForeignKey(
                                Category,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The last model indicates the locations of the project.

```
class ProjectLocation(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
                                Project,
                                on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    projectLocation = models.ForeignKey(
                                Location,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I was trying to render in a template a list of projects.
I want to show the informations (Categories and Locations) related to each project. 
How can achieve that ? 
Using the query Project.objects.all() doesn't allow me to access the fields "projectLocation" and "projectCategory".

Comment: Your project model doesnt have these fields. To access related models You must add `_set` to field names like `projectLocation_set`. And remember that all() returns list not a just single element.

Comment: projectLocation or projectlocation? should I add ProjectLocation objects to the context of the view ?

Comment: You got the main object in context so there is no need, during template execution all the needed data will be fetched so no,you dont need to add related object to context.More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342333/getting-and-displaying-related-objects-in-django

Comment: It works as a charm. One last question, does calling _set slower the template rendering a lot ?

Comment: a lot? it always depends on database which You are using and the size of dataset. But You shouldnt care about performance at this point i guess, all performance upgrades should be made when there is performance problem 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `related_name` to your foriegn key fields, and you can access them by this name.

For example ProjectCategory:

```
class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='categories')
```

so now you can do:
`project.categories.all()`