# Django - get objects from one table who belong to another objects in other table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a project to do which consists to creating a note manager in Django. So I created my tables in sql with foreign keys. And I have been facing a problem for several days. I have a page that lists all the students in the database, and I would like by clicking on a link, to be able to display all the notes belonging to each student.

Here's my SQL tables (étudiants = students / Notes = grades) :

[sql students table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zswNy.png) /
[sql grade table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1BN0.png)

models.py :

```
class Etudiants(models.Model):
    numeroetudiant = models.BigIntegerField(db_column='numeroEtudiant', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    groupe = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'etudiants'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom + " " + self.prenom


class Notes(models.Model):
    examens = models.ForeignKey(Examens, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='examens', blank=True, null=True)
    etudiant = models.ForeignKey(Etudiants, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='etudiant', blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    appreciation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'notes'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Note de " + self.etudiant.nom + " " + self.etudiant.prenom + " à l'examen de " + self.examens.titre
```

views.py :

```
def etudiants(request):
    etudiants = Etudiants.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'etudiants.html', {'etudiants': etudiants, 'notes': notes})


def affichenote(request, id):
    notes = Notes.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'affichenote.html', {'notes': notes})
```

urls.py :

```
   path('etudiants/', views.etudiants, name='etudiants'),
   path('affichenote/<int:id>/', views.affichenote, name='affiche-note'),
```

etudiants.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div class="row">
  {% for Etudiants in etudiants %}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ Etudiants.nom }} {{ Etudiants.prenom }} </h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          E-mail : {{ Etudiants.email }} <br>
          Numéro étudiant : {{ Etudiants.numeroetudiant }} <br>
          Groupe : {{ Etudiants.groupe }} <br>
        </p> 
        <a href="../affichenote/{{Etudiants.id}}/" class="btn btn-primary">Voir les notes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproductible example [repro]? and can you please share your views.py and templates that how you are doing it currently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting and displaying related objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342333/getting-and-displaying-related-objects-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want by clicking on a link, you would be able to display all the notes belonging to each student. So you can apply [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) through student id in the following way:

views.py

```py
def etudiants(request):
    etudiants = Etudiants.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'etudiants.html', {'etudiants': etudiants})
  
def affichenote(request, id):
    notes = Notes.objects.filter(etudiant__id=id)
    return render(request, 'affichenote.html', {'notes': notes})
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('etudiants/', views.etudiants, name='etudiants'),
    path('affichenote/<int:id>/', views.affichenote, name='affichenote'),

]
```

etudiants.html

```html
<div class="row">
  {% for etudiant in etudiants %}
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ etudiant.nom }} {{ etudiant.prenom }} </h5>
        <p class="card-text">
          E-mail : {{ etudiant.email }} <br>
          Numéro étudiant : {{ etudiant.numeroetudiant }} <br>
          Groupe : {{ etudiant.groupe }} <br>
        </p> 
       
        <a href="{% url 'affichenote' etudiant.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Voir les notes</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Then, in `affichenote.html`, you can access all notes, relating to a student.

affichenote.html

```html
<body>
{% for note in notes  %}
    <p>{{note.edudiant}}</p>
    <p>{{note.note}}</p>
    <p>{{note.appreciation}}</p>

{% endfor %}
</body>
```

`Note:` Models in django generally written in singular form, it will be better if you name it `Etudiant` and `Note` instead of <s>`Etudiants`</s> and <s>`Notes`</s> respectively, as `s` is already itself added as the suffix for every model.