# How to query objects from parent table along with data from related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model 'Product' to upload products.

```
class Product(BaseModel):
  ...
  ...
  class Meta:
    db_table = TABLE_PREFIX + "product"
```

I have another table with product as foreignkey.

```
class ProductImage(BaseModel):
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')

  class Meta:
    db_table = TABLE_PREFIX + "product_image"
```

In home page i want to display these products.
I have the home view as

```
def home(request):
  category_obj = Category.objects.all()
  product_obj = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')
  
  context = {
        "title": "Home",
        "product_obj": product_obj,
        "category_obj": category_obj,
  }
  return render(request, "home/index.html", context)
```

In the template I want to display the products along with the images.

I am able to display all the details in the template except images.

```
<div class="dFlex product-list-wrap">
  {% for product in product_obj %}
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="" alt="Product Image">
    </div>
    <h4>{{ product.name}}</h4>
    <p>{{ product.description}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

How do i display images on my template?
How can I query images also while querying products?

Thank you

Comment: Here each product can have *zero*, *one* or *many* images, so there is not per se a single image, nor is there per se any image...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting and displaying related objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342333/getting-and-displaying-related-objects-in-django)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I think the code is working and i am getting the image as related manager object. I want to display the first image on my template. Can you please show me how to display the first image on template. Thank you.